# Core constant expression and array indexing

Tags: c++, constant-expression

The reference is to the code segment under the following:

[Core constant expressions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_expression#Core_constant_expressions)

```
int main() {
    const std::size_t tabsize = 50;
    int tab[tabsize]; // OK: tabsize is a constant expression

    std::size_t n = 50;
    const std::size_t sz = n;
    int tab2[sz]; // error: sz is not a constant expression
                  // because sz is not initialized with a constant expression
}
```

When I compile above code segment using (gcc 4.2):

> g++ -ggdb -pedantic -std=c++14 -Wall

for the line highlighted as error in the code, only the following warning is generated:

```
 warning: variable length arrays are a C99 feature
      [-Wvla-extension]
    int tab2[sz]; // error: sz is not a constant expression
            ^
```

This seems to contradict the requirement outlined in the above link that a core constant expression must not evaluate an lvalue->rvalue implicit conversion, unless the value:

> has integral or enumeration type and refers to a complete non-volatile
>   const object, which is initialized with a constant expression

Appreciate your thoughts.

Comment: GCC have an *extension* to the C++ languages that it allows [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array). It's of course non-standard and not portable, so avoid it in your own code in favor of [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supporting variable-length arrays is a compiler extension, which the standard generally permits as long as it doesn't make conformant code behave differently, and as long as they *say* that it's an extension (which GCC does with that warning):

> A conforming implementation may have extensions (including additional library functions), provided they do not alter the behavior of any well-formed program. Implementations are required to diagnose programs that use such extensions that are ill-formed according to this document.
>   Having done so, however, they can compile and execute such programs.

<sup>[[intro.compliance]/8](http://eel.is/c++draft/intro#compliance-8)</sup>

If desired, you can disable all extensions via `-pedantic-errors`.